# How to count elements of array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have an array with a particular size (100 for example), which is filled with user input. However, the user might not necessarily enter enough data to fill the entire array.

I want to count the elements of the array which the user entered. How can I do this?

I tried by this for loop:

```
int COUNT=0;
for( int i=0; i<size; i++)
    if (Student[i]=1) //which means this element is true, not empty element.
        COUNT++;
cout<< COUNT+1 << "\n";
```

But this code gives an error on this line:

`if (Students[i]==1)`

Also, if the user enters repeated elements, I just want to count the unique elements (count each value one time).

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#define size 100
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string Students_;
    string word2;

    getline(cin, Students_);
    int k;
    int l;
    k = Students_.find("[");
    Students_.erase(0, k + 1);
    l = Students_.find("]");
    string line2 = Students_.erase(l);
    stringstream iss(line2);
    string Students[size];
    int counter = 0;
    while (getline(iss, word2, ';') && counter < size) {
        Students[counter++] = word2;
    }

    int COUNT = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (Students[i] == 1)
            COUNT++;
    cout << COUNT + 1 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The input for example is:

```
Students=[8347,Islam Said,(ARC135,ARC114,ARC134,ARC135);8256,Esraa Said,(ARC134,ARC135,ARC114);8336,Ismail Said,(ARC134,ARC135,ARC114);8285,Ismail Adballah,(ARC114,ARC135,ARC134,ARC114);8349,Esraa Kassem,(ARC135,ARC114,ARC134);8505,Bassant Kassem,(ARC114,ARC135,ARC134,ARC114);8381,Ismail Kassem,(ARC135,ARC134,ARC114,ARC135);8360,Bassant AbdAlrahman,(ARC114);8498,Mohamed Kamal,(ARC135,ARC114,ARC134);8255,Ali Bassem,(ARC114,ARC135);8437,Mohamed Said,(ARC135);8524,Osama Adballah,(ARC114,ARC135);8334,Osama Kamal,(ARC114,ARC135,ARC134);8501,Esraa Tarek,(ARC135,ARC134);8394,Ahmed Zain,(ARC134,ARC135)]
```

The input is not constant, it's just an example.

Comment: `s/if (Student[i]=1)/if (Student[i]==1)/` - also for the love of all that is decent please enable compiler warnings and take notice of them (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`).

Comment: Use a `std::vector` if you do not know how many elements the user will enter.

Comment: First of all, enable more compiler warnings. Then include a [mcve] and a clear problem statement in all debugging questions as instructed in the [ask]. And last: One question per question please.

Comment: How do you initialize the array? BTW - seems strange to have an array of int(?) where elements are either 1 or unintialized/empty but there migth be a use case for it.

Comment: `But this code make an error, what is the error?` You tell us. How do you know that there is an error if you don't know that the error is?

Comment: I wrote " #define size 100 " in the top of the code ... But the user is not forced to enter 100 element, the user may enter less than 100 element but not more .... my question is how could I know the number of the elements which the user entered?? how I could count them?

Comment: Post a complete example! How is Student[] defined? How is it initialized? How does the user enter data? Without that information we can't really help you. It seems that a lot of programmers are ready to help with the code, you just don't let them.

Comment: Isn't `counter` the number you want??

Comment: Students is an array of string, i.e. `string Students[size];` so you can't compare a `string` to a number like you do here: `if (Students[i] == 1)`. A string must be compared to a string! Example: `if (Students[i] == "somename")`

Answer (score 1):

Try `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`

In C++ always use `std::vector`. There are several inbuilt functions and an extended functionality.

`std::vector` has a method `size()` which returns the number of elements in the vector.

(Yes, this is tongue-in-cheek answer)

Comment: Can you write a code for example to explain more, please?

Comment: OP does not want size of array, he wants to know how many elements are entered. In addition your `sizeof` solution should never be used in C++. It is unsafe and can give wrong results, template solution is superior.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot How is it unsafe?  `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` will always give you the size of an array.

Comment: @NathanOliver not if array was passed into function and decayed or otherwise was converted to pointer. What worse it fails silently, giving wrong result.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Then it is not an array but a pointer.  It is always safe to use it on an array though.

Comment: @NathanOliver technically speaking you are correct. But in most cases difference between an array and pointer to first element is neglible, so people use it interchangeably. So you have _dynamically allocated array_ (really a pointer) and want to know it size. Most people who are not aware of difference, e.g. by being new to the languade, are going to try old approach and will get wrong result. Some people are going to write `void foo(int x[4])` and get wrong result.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot And that is a problem with the way the language is taught.  A pointer and an array are two different things that should be made absolutely clear to new students.  The cases where the array decays into a pointer detailed so new programmers understand the pitfalls of passing arrays by value.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `if` statement you're assigning a value instead of checking it.

Try

```
if (Student[i] == 1)
```

Comment: I tried if (Student[i] == 1) ... But still there is an error!

Comment: Your Students variable is an array of strings. You cannot compare strings with integers.