# How to count integers in an array that is not filled completely

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, integer

I have an type int array with a fixed size (10) that is not filled up entirely.

I want to count the how many integers are in the array so that I know what value to index the array to if I want to add an integer to the array. (so that I am not replacing another value)

```
//Define Array
int counter=0;
int scores[10] = {92,87,94,99,96};

//Count how many elements are in the score array
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (scores[i] == 1)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

When I output the variable counter I get the value of "0".

I looked at a couple Stack Overflow posts and I do seem to find anything that will help me find a solution!  Any help or suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I was able to get the answer to my question, however I regret posting because I now have 2 reputation points!  You guys are harsh!
This is the correct answer

```
//Define Array
    int counter=0;
    int scores[10] = {92,87,94,99,96};

    //Count how many elements are in the score array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (scores[i] != 0)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: None of the shown score values are `1`, so what do you expect?

Comment: Use a `std::vecton<int>` and check the current size.

Comment: @crashmstr
I thought that condition (scores[i] ==1) would check if there is a value in that index.

Comment: No, it checks to see if that value is equal to `1`, exactly as `== 1` should mean.

Comment: @Humanid1652487954543 there is a value at every index.  `int` does not have a "no value" property.

Comment: @crashmstr
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072735/how-to-count-elements-of-array-in-c> Was posted as an answer so I assumed that is what the code meant.  

What would be your solution to my question?

Comment: @user0042 Would you mind posting it as an answer, but writing the actual line of code that will print out the # of elements in the array.  Anything I look up online relating to vecton<int> does not give me an example

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: it should be `std::vector` not `std:vecton` that was a typo.

Comment: The array has ten integers. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can consider that an element of the array that contains 0 (or -1) is a not-filled element.

In any case each element of the array shall contain either an actual value or 0.

This initialization

```
int scores[10] = {92,87,94,99,96};
```

is equivalent to

```
int scores[10] = {92,87,94,99,96,0,0,0,0,0};
```

So the loop can look like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( scores ) / sizeof( *scores ); i++ )
{
    if ( scores[i] != 0)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

If to use the value -1 for a non-filled element then you have to initialize non-filled elements explicitly as for example

```
int scores[10] = {92,87,94,99,96,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
```

and the loop will look like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( scores ) / sizeof( *scores ); i++ )
{
    if ( scores[i] != -1)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I will accept as an answer.  My only question is why did you initilize 'i' as size_t?  would saying int i not work?

Comment: @Humanid1652487954543 The type of value returned by the sizeof operator is size_t that is an unsigned type. The compiler can issue a warning that you are comparing an object of signed type (I) with an object of unsigned type (returned by the expression with sizeof)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do all that.
Just **increment the counter** each time you store a number in the array, and the counter itself will tell you at which index you need to store next number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector`, then the `size` method:

```
std::vector v={1,2,4,8};
cout << "Vector size is: " << v.size() << "\n"
```

Comment: Maybe show push_back() / emplace_back() to show the OP that items can be added.